# Spring Boot: Not to use TLSv1.0

Tags: spring, security, ssl, spring-boot

Right now my spring boot application supports TLS1.0 TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. How do I disable TLS1.0 to avoid beast attacks?

Below is my `application.yml`

```
server:
  address: localhost
  port: 8443
  sessionTimeout: 30
  ssl:
    client-auth: need
    key-store: keystore.jks
    key-store-password: xxxx
    key-alias: dev-demo
    key-password: xxxx
    protocol: TLS
    trust-store: truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: xxxx
    ciphers: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
             TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
             TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
             TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
             TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
             TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
             TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
             TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
             TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
             TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
             TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

  tomcat:
    #default max-threads is 200
    max-threads: 200
    basedir: ./
    access-log-enabled: true
    access-log-pattern: "%h %l %u %t %r %s %b"
security:
  require-ssl: true
```

Comment: Are you using an embedded container? If so, which one?

Comment: Updated question with `application.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Even though the question was posted in 2015, posting an answer here for those who get here:

Springboot app allows to add Customizers which can be used to customize the connector to disable protocols or other properties.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(TomcatConnectorCustomizer connectorCustomizer) {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(connectorCustomizer);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public TomcatConnectorCustomizer connectorCustomizer() {
    return new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setAttribute("sslEnabledProtocols", "TLSv1.2");
        }
    };
}
```

More details are available here on [YoursAndMyIdeas](http://yoursandmyideas.com/2018/01/20/how-to-disable-ssl-tls-protocols-in-springboot/)